# 'screen -R' is slow when creating a new screen

Tags: gnu-screen

When starting a new screen session with `screen -R`, some text at the bottom of the screen informs me it is creating a new screen. It takes about 5 seconds before bash starts seemingly because of this. However, if I start a new screen with `screen`, it takes less than a second to start. Is there a setting I can change to force `screen -R` to start a new screen as soon as it can when there is none available?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. There is a message wait time for pop-ups like this that defaults to 5 seconds. Adding `msgwait 1` to .screenrc changes the message to display for 1 second.

Apparently the message will also end early upon typing. Herp durp.